# Drupal 8 site pages not loading

Tags: drupal-8

Fresh install of Drupal 8 not working properly. Index, login and logout pages only working in localhost. Other pages not loading and showing error:

`The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.`

Comment: This problem was asked  [Here](https://www.drupal.org/node/2833294) in drupal user forum.  Do some digging.

Answer (score 0):

Install your version of php-crul module. In my case php7.0-crul missing.

> sudo apt-get install php7.0-crul
>
> service apache2 restart

solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by , (on **Ubuntu 18.04** & **LAMP**)

1. Open the .htaccess file in the site's folder(most probably found in the directory /var/www/html/site folder). It will be hidden .Therefore make sure that the show hidden button is turned on.
2. If this line(rewritebase) is uncommented ,make it commented (add # infront of RewriteBase)
   [image]
3. Remove all the backups created in the drupal's folder (will be named .htaccess~ , .htaccess~~ and so on...)
4. Reload your site and open other pages of your sites
                                  -- Have a nice day --